# SaveFileDialog make problems with streamwriter in c#

Tags: c#, using

I want bild save file from contents in streamwriter, but in this code

```
SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
                savefile.FileName = "unknown.txt";
                savefile.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*|";
                if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
                    sw.WriteLine("Test line");
                    sw.WriteLine("Test line2");
                    sw.WriteLine("Test line3");
                }
```

in lines `sw.WriteLine("Test line2");
                        sw.WriteLine("Test line3");` , are errors, `sw` didn't exist !

But rarely i used code

`using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("\unknow.txt", false,System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
                        sw.WriteLine("Test line");
                        sw.WriteLine("Test line2");
                        sw.WriteLine("Test line3");`

and everything work's fine ! Where is problem ?
Thank's !

Comment: Go back to Visual Studio, hold CTRL then press K followed by D. The IDE will reformat the code, which will make the problem pop out (as stated in the answers, you're missing the curly braces around the code which is supposed to be the using block

Answer (score 6):

You just need to add braces:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, 
          false, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
{
     sw.WriteLine("Test line");
     sw.WriteLine("Test line2");
     sw.WriteLine("Test line3");
}
```

The variable `sw` is local to the scope of the `using()` statement. Without the braces that was only the first WriteLine().

The scoping rules for `using()` are the same as for `if()`, you were already using that correctly.

Comment: Thanks..huh...maybe i am tired, i din't see this little thing

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
savefile.FileName = "unknown.txt";
savefile.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*|";

if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
      { // You are missing this one.. 
                    sw.WriteLine("Test line");
                    sw.WriteLine("Test line2");
                    sw.WriteLine("Test line3");
       } //.. and this one!
 }
```

When you don't use the braces it will only see the first following line of code.

Answer (score 0):

`Using statement`, when it defines a scope at the end of which an object will be disposed. See [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).